# Invalid format when attempting to create AWS Signature V4 to sign API Gateway URL POST request

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, sign

I am using the code found here to base my signing class on:

https://gist.github.com/yvanin/0bdf68c1139ad698519e

From this I have been able to build an Authorisation header, but when this is passed along with my POST request, it fails with the error

The format of value '*Redacted*' is invalid.

When I compare my authorisation header composure to an example found on the internet, it looks pretty much spot on (although i don't use Content-Type header as the request has no payload). Can anyone assist with where I might be going wrong?

Internet example is the top one below, mine is underneath. I have changed the relevant access key and signature data to obfuscate real values (EDIT: and obviously I'm trying to reach the API Gateway service, not IAM, so that's  why I have execute-api in the header, have also tried apigateway and neither have any effect...)

```
            // AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIDEXAMPLE/20150830/us-east-1/iam/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-date, Signature=5d672d79c15b13162d9279b0855cfba6789a8edb4c82c400e06b5924a6f2b5d7
            // AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AAAAI7T5JMMLSKVKA6EQ/20180302/ap-southeast-2/execute-api/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-date, Signature=856bc41f18582836b56a02d9563c8f4f621fce7338ae2ec3afabe254a1543667
```

EDIT: Solved! So, when I first used the Sig V4 code at the github link, there was an extension function ParseQueryString that wouldn't resolve. It was because I was missing a reference to System.Net.Http.Formatting. Attempts to locate this library and add it failed, so I wrote my own extension method to do what I believed that function was doing.

Clearly my version of ParseQueryString was not right, because I finally solved the issue of the missing reference by locating a very specific version of the assembly to add via NuGet (any other versions produce the following error:

```
Unable to find a version of 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client' that is compatible with 'System.Net.Http.Formatting
```

The specific version I required was:

```
PM> Install-Package System.Net.Http.Formatting -Version 4.0.20505
```

Once that was installed, and the ParseQueryString extension method I wrote was replaced with the standard one, viola! I now have a response from my API Gateway using IAM authorisation. It's a beautiful day :)

Comment: *"The format of value 'Redacted' is invalid."*  Does it really say "Redacted" in the error message?

Comment: The service component of the credential apparently should be `execute-api`.  This is suggested by the fact that ARNs use this as the service identifier for deployed APIs.  It's `apigateway` when you're sending a request to the provisioning endpoint for API Gateway itself.

Comment: Sorry, the redacted is me - I replaced the actual auth header with that.. and to Michaels point, I have tried execute-api as well, with no difference :(  EDIT: Michael if you look at the bottom authorisation header, you can see I am using execute-api? The one above, using 'ami' is just an example I was looking at to make sure the formatting is correct. So I am using the right service.

Comment: Update - added solution into original post. Thanks for looking into it anyway Michael :)

Comment: Glad you found the issue... since this may not be particularly useful to future visitors, you may want to consider deleting the question.